# Adding SQL Login does not work

Tags: sql-server

I'm receiving this error message in Visual Studio 2010:

> Cannot open database \"Northwind\" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'Mike\Mike Simpson'

When I try to add the user, which is me. Then SQL server says

> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The login already has an account
>   under a different user name.

Here is my connection string:

> "Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"

I'm using SSMS not SQL Server express.
I don't know what else I should do. This application used to work before I zipped it up.

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem and this is what solved it for me

sp_changedbowner 'sa'

Then just re-map your login DomainName\UserNameto the database (double click on the login->User Mapping->check your DB->check Datareader/Datawriter->Ok)

Picked it up from here
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic788865-146-1.aspx

hope this helps some one

Answer (score 0):

Check if their exist any other  connection with same DSN.If this is not the case then do check if connection is properly established or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a user that alleady exists.

Check out this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9faf79d0-f4b6-4b6c-9505-68cd2ec636af/the-login-already-has-an-account-under-a-different-user-name-microsoft-sql-server-error-15063?forum=sqlsecurity

> I would recommend looking at the SIDs on both the server scope
>   (sys.server_principals) and the database scope
>   (sys.database_principals) to help you correlate the name of the user
>   mapped to the login.
>   There are two likely possibilities for the root cause of this problem:
>
> 1)      You restored a DB that contained already users mapped in it
>   that are conflicting with your application.
>
> 2)      The model DB was modified and the user was created there. In
>   this case every time a new DB is created the new user will be mapped
>   as well.
>
> I would recommend using T-SQL script directly instead of using the SQL
>   Server Management Studio while debugging this scenario. SSMS is not
>   resilient to this kind of problems  and it will probably fail to
>   execute the operations you need.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I read the other link you provided. But I still don't know what steps I should take or what i should search to find more info on how to correct this. Currently, I"m looking up SID. This query gives me the list of items but I don't know what to do with it. SELECT *  FROM sys.server_principals

Comment: @JacobPressures , Maybe the second suggestion on that link can help you? A way to assign the account instead of creating a new one.

Comment: SELECT *  FROM sys.server_principals  SELECT *  FROM sys.database_principals Ok the first query has the username the second one does not.

Comment: Ok the user is there in both tables when i run this query: select * from sys.server_principals ssp inner join sys.database_principals sdb on (sdb.sid = ssp.sid)

Comment: I've also tried the information on this page: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/. If i try to change the from DBO to my username it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was the connection string. I'm using a NAMED INSTANCE rather than a default instance. Thus my connection string needed to have two slashes and the named instance afterwards.

"Data Source=Localhost\Arius;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"

When i made this change everything worked. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem because I was planning on adding User A as a login to a db I'd just created, but turned out I'd accidentally made User A the owner. That meant User A did in fact already have a login - "dbo" - since they were the owner.

This error would be a lot more helpful if it told you WHICH login was already added for the user.